# Why is this not removing duplicate copies?

Tags: memory, arraylist, duplicates

I want to be able to add itemOrders to an ArrayList but then check to see if the itemOrder is already there. If that particular itemOrder is already in the ArrayList I only want one copy to remain. I can't figure out why this isn't deleting duplicate copies. I've even tried converting itemOrder to a string and checking to see if the strings are the same and deleting that way but I can't get it to work. Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void add(ItemOrder itemOrder) {
        this.list.add(itemOrder);
        for (int i=0; i< this.list.size(); i++){
            if (this.list.get(i).equals(itemOrder)){
               this.list.remove(i);
            }
        }
}
```

I get results like this.

Memory Format

[ItemOrder@4d459b26]

[ItemOrder@4d459b26, ItemOrder@343d0d2b]

[ItemOrder@4d459b26, ItemOrder@343d0d2b, ItemOrder@142b9cd8]

String Format

[silly putty, 3.95 (10 for 19.99), 1]

[silly putty, 3.95 (10 for 19.99), 1, silly string, 3.5 (10 for 14.5), 0]

[silly putty, 3.95 (10 for 19.99), 1, silly string, 3.5 (10 for 14.5), 0, silly putty, 3.95 (10 for 19.99), 1]

So what I think is happening is that its checking the memory of the itemOrder and since that's not the same it's letting a duplicate through. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you implement `equals` properly for your `ItemOrder`?

Answer (score 2):

> So what I think is happening is that its checking the memory of the itemOrder and since that's not the same it's letting a duplicate through. How can I fix this?

Yes, that is the default behaviour.

If you want the state / contents of the object to be compared, you have to implement `equals` (and if you do that, you also have to implement `hashCode` to match it).

In addition to that, as @alfasin points out, you cannot just remove elements from the list while iterating over it. That messes up indexes. Just check if the element is already in the list, and only add it if not.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement equals. Do I have to go to my ItemOrder class and add a method there? Also I want it to be able to update so I always want the new ItemOrder to take place. So if I check and it's already there I want to replace it.